# How To Enable 64Bit OS With VM VirtualBox (On Windows 7)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, 64-bit

I recently installed Oracle VM VirtualBox on Windows 7 (64Bit) however when i go to setup an OS the version list only shows 32Bit OS.

I was planning on installing an Ubuntu ISO (64Bit) but was hoping to have Windows 7 64Bit OS also.

So my question is how can i get the versions list to show 64Bit OS also?

Comment: Does your process have hardware virtualization support? Is it enabled in BIOS?

Comment: I am not sure how to do this, do i need to go in to my main PC Bios to find this option? Since my computer is already operating on 64Bit why would i need to alter the Bios?

Comment: Then you need to consult CPU and motherboard manual to see if hardware virtualization supported and how to enable it. Since you are not include information of your hardware into question, I can not help you with it. And host bitness is irrelevant, because VirtualBox can support 64-bit guests on 32-bit hosts, but [hardware virtualization must be enabled](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests).

Comment: Specs: Window 7 (64-Bit) SP1, AMD FX-8350 Eight-Core Processor, 8GB RAM, AMD Radeon HD 7700 Series

Answer (score -1):

To solve this i had to go into the main PC Bios in windows and then change the virtualization option to Enabled then it worked ok.